# Redux saga & redux toolkit

Tags: redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I been trying to introduce redux sagas and redux tool kit to my project. The problem I am having at the moment is that the watcher saga is not catching on the dispatched action in the `takeEvery` effect and running the handler. I can't see anything wrong with the code. Can anyone Help!!!

```js
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware  } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import createReducer from './rootReducer';
import sagas from './rootSaga';


const configureAdminStore = (initialState = {}) => {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  
    // sagaMiddleware: Makes redux-sagas work
    const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, logger];

  
    const store = configureStore({
      reducer: createReducer(),
      middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware({thunk: false}), ...middlewares],
      preloadedState: initialState,
      devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    });
    
    sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
  
    return store;
  }

  export default configureAdminStore;
```

```js
import {put, take, takeEvery, call} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {getAll} from './environmentSlice'
import {confApi} from '../../service/conf-api'
import { getData } from '../../lib/conf-api-response';


function* getAllEnvironments() {
    const response = yield call(confApi.admin.getEnvironments());
    const {environments} = yield call(getData(response));
    yield put(getAll(environments));
}

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export function* watchGetAllEnvironments() {
     yield takeEvery(getAll().type, getAllEnvironments);
}
```

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const environmentSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'environments',
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        getAll: (state, action) => {
            state = action.payload
        },
    },
  })

  export const {getAll} = environmentSlice.actions

  export const { getAllSuccess } = environmentSlice.actions;
  
  export default environmentSlice.reducer

  export const environmentSelector = (state) => state.environments
```

```js
import {all} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {watchGetAllEnvironments} from './environments/environmentSaga'

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        watchGetAllEnvironments(),
    ])
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are just taking `getAll().type` twice - once in `watchGetAllEnvironments` and once in `getAllEnvironments`.

Which means that `watchGetAllEnvironments` will execute `getAllEnvironments`, but that will immediately pause and wait for another `getAll` action to be dispatched, which probably never happens.

So you probably want to remove that first `take` in `getAllEnvironments`.

Also, you can just `take(getAll)`, there's not need to `take(getAll().type)`.

Comment: Oh sorry I added that there accidentally whilst debugging, even with that removed it doesn't work, it never gets to getAllEnvironments. I have even tried changing the action type watchGetAllEnvironments is listening to.

Comment: Okay. Next thing: if the second snippet is your `rootSaga.js`, you are importing `undefined` from it. It is exporting the named export `watchGetAllEnvironments`, but you only import the default export and name it `sagas`.

Comment: I have got a rootSaga.js, didn't add to the stack overflow, I have added that now. Sorry for the miss information.

Comment: I got it working pretty straightforward. Maybe compare your code with this codesandbox?
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-keller-6h4bw?file=/src/index.js

Also, log out your imports everywhere, maybe you have a circular import somewhere which would make something `undefined`.

Comment: Your right I just tried doing this on a different application and it works, I am probably missing something on the above code. Thanks for all your help, at least I know now its possible!

Answer (score 9):

If you're interested in creating sagas that can resolve/reject async thunk actions then have a look at the [saga-toolkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saga-toolkit) package - I created and use.

`slice.js`

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { createSagaAction  } from 'saga-toolkit'

const name = 'example'

const initialState = {
  result: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
}

export const fetchThings = createSagaAction(`${name}/fetchThings`)
export const doSomeMoreAsyncStuff = createSagaAction(`${name}/doSomeMoreAsyncStuff`)

const slice = createSlice({
  name,
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchThings.pending]: () => ({
      loading: true,
    }),
    [fetchThings.fulfilled]: ({ payload }) => ({
      result: payload,
      loading: false,
    }),
    [fetchThings.rejected]: ({ error }) => ({
      error,
      loading: false,
    }),
  },
})

export default slice.reducer
```

`sagas.js`

```js
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { takeLatestAsync, takeEveryAsync, putAsync } from 'saga-toolkit'
import API from 'hyper-super-api'
import * as actions from './slice'

function* fetchThings() {
  const result = yield call(() => API.get('/things'))

  const anotherResult = yield putAsync(actions.doSomeMoreAsyncStuff()) // waits for doSomeMoreAsyncStuff to finish !

  return result
}

function* doSomeMoreAsyncStuff() {
  ...
  return 'a value for another result'
}

export default [
  takeLatestAsync(actions.fetchThings.pending, fetchThings), // takeLatestAsync: behaves a bit like debounce
  takeEveryAsync(actions.doSomeMoreAsyncStuff.pending, doSomeMoreAsyncStuff), // each action will start a new saga thread
]
```

Comment: Hey, this is cool but I’m not really understanding the use case because it seems like it mostly does what the Toolkit createAsyncThunk does already.  What am I missing?  What’s the use case that led you to create this?

Comment: This allows you to use sagas easily in the redux-toolkit ecosystem, similarly to the thunks. Sagas allows you to manage more complex app flows. For instance, you can wait for other sagas, actions to start, finish, basically think sagas as threads, redux-sagas allows you to do whatever you want with these threads. It is fantastic when it comes to implementing a complex app, trust me. :)

Comment: I've added some more example to the project page.

Comment: any solution for typescript?

Comment: @haxpanel I have also similar problem but unable to make api request with saga-toolkit. Already posted on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545338/unable-to-dispatch-action-by-using-saga-toolkit-and-redux-toolkit-together. Can you please look into this ?

Comment: Added TS type coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Official doc might be helpful,

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

import monitorReducersEnhancer from './enhancers/monitorReducers'
import loggerMiddleware from './middleware/logger'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

export default function configureStore(preloadedState) {
  const middlewares = [loggerMiddleware, thunkMiddleware]
  const middlewareEnhancer = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)

  const enhancers = [middlewareEnhancer, monitorReducersEnhancer]
  const composedEnhancers = composeWithDevTools(...enhancers)

  const store = createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState, composedEnhancers)

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => store.replaceReducer(rootReducer))
  }

  return store
}
```

Source: [official example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#manual-store-setup)

Answer (score 0):

If this would help any new comers, I found redux-toolkit cool but still a bit complicated, especially when you throw in sagas (which is essentially async magic and mystery at first). I ended up making something similar I called [saga slice](https://saga-slice.github.io/). It's a spin off on redux toolkit but with sagas added to the mix from the getgo. You basically have your reducers, which manipulate state, and your sagas, which make asynchronous called and dispatch other states. To simplify the example you set, it would end up looking like this:

```js
import { put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { createModule } from 'saga-slice';

const environmentSlice = createModule({
    name: 'environments',
    initialState: [],
    reducers: {
        getAll: () => {},
        getAllSuccess: (state, payload) => {
            
            state.splice(0, state.length);

            payload.forEach(data => state.push(data));
        },
    },

    sagas: (A) => ({
        *[A.getAll]({ payload }) {
            
            
            const response = yield call(confApi.admin.getEnvironments());
            const { environments } = yield call(getData(response));
            

            yield put(A.getAllSuccess(environments));
        }
    })
});
```

This would essentially do the same thing you're trying to do without the confusing `watchGetAllEnvironments` and `rootSaga` stuff (which I find very puzzling). Saga slice is configurable to use `takeEvery`, `takeOne`, or whatever other effects you want to use without too much hassle. It's configuration objects, not `yield takeEvery()`. I also include helpers to facilitate some of the stuff you're doing by including an `axios` wrapper that ties in with saga's task cancellation, stream lines request lifecycles, and builds default CRUD modules based on standard REST principles. Check out documentation for a more thorough explanation and feel free to open issues!

Answer (score 0):

In watchGetAllEnvironments, you can use getAll.toString() to catch the action and prevent dispatch an action. This method is described in https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction.