# Unable to dispatch action by using saga-toolkit and redux-toolkit together

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-toolkit

I am tried to use saga-toolkit package to create saga action but getting some error while dispatching, although I went to official documentation of saga-toolkit npm package but something is missing over there i think and I am not able to figure out what going wrong. This is official documentation link https://npm.io/package/saga-toolkit

And I wanted to pass some argument while dispatching the action but getting error in console like
"Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions."

saga-toolkit provide createSagaAction which is resposibe for creating saga action but I am still get the above during dispatching

dataSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { createSagaAction } from "saga-toolkit";

export const fetchData = createSagaAction("data/fetchData");

const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "data",
  initialState: {
    data: [],
    error: null,
    loading: false,
  },


  extraReducers: {
    [fetchData.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [fetchData.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
    [fetchData.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export default dataSlice.reducer;
```

dataSagas.js

```
import { put, call, fork } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { takeLatestAsync, putAsync } from "saga-toolkit";
import * as actions from "./feature/dataSlice";
import { getDataApi } from "./api";

function* onLoadData({payload}) {
    
  const result = yield call(getDataApi, payload);
  return result;
}

function* onLoadData() {
  yield takeLatestAsync(actions.fetchData.type, onLoadDataAsync);
}

export const dataSagas = [fork(onLoadData)];
```

rootSaga.js

```
import { all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { dataSagas } from "./dataSagas";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([...dataSagas]);
}
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import DataReducer from "./feature/dataSlice";
import rootSaga from "./rootSaga";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    data: DataReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({ thunk: false }).concat(sagaMiddleware),
});

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

App.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchData } from "./redux/feature/dataSlice";

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <h2>Calling API using Saga-toolkit</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: FYI, redux toolkit library recommends using redux-thunk instead of saga. However, saga is possible to work with RTK.

Comment: Yeah I know redux toolkit library recommends using redux-thunk and I have already done that but I wanted to do with saga-toolkit package

Comment: Your `dataSagas.js` looks a bit odd. Why not exporting default `export default [
  takeLatestAsync(actions.fetchData.type, onLoadDataAsync),
]`, then `import dataSagas from "./dataSagas"` ? Also, you've got 2 `onLoadData` - I suppose first one is `onLoadDataAsync`?

Comment: Also, have you managed to set up `redux-saga` properly? Have you seen it working without `saga-toolkit`? That's kind of step 0. Documentation should have mentioned this.

Comment: Actually initially I tried that way only as per mention in your docmentation. But it was not working, so I tried to change things little bit. With createAsyncThunk it's working, I have try to replace saga-toolkit then it's not working. If you need the github link please let me know, I really want to fetch the data with this particular package. It's look good actually. You know saga is very helpful on large scale application. I have show you all file

Comment: If you have use this package to fetch data then it is possible for you to share the git repo link , i will take the reference and I will do changes according to that.

Comment: It seems like that still uses thunks internally, so you probably just cannot turn thunks off. That said, we as the Redux team really do not recommend sagas for most things any more. Even if you have an app that has a real need for sagas (using advanced features like action channels, forking etc.) we recommend using less convoluted tools like RTK Query, createAsyncThunks or thunks for simple use cases like data fetching in the same code base. Also, Redux Toolkit by now also contains a listener middleware that takes over most other things redux-saga was used for previously.

Comment: @phry Yeah I am totally agree with you. I found this saga-toolkit package and I thought to give it a try, but there is no proper documentation how to work with it. I have used redux-toolkit a lot but wanted to give it a try with saga-toolkit package.

Comment: @James I'll upload an example app for you today.

Comment: @haxpanel Please let me know once you have an example for that

Comment: @James find the example here https://github.com/janoist1/saga-toolkit/tree/master/example let me know if any questions, have fun ! 

Comment: @James FYI use redux devtools to see the action stream

Comment: Since redux toolkit doesn't recommend Sagas anymore would it be better to remove Redux Tool Kit from an older redux app we are updating and keep the sagas or find a way to make the large codebase of Sagas work? Sagas with "configureStore" do not play nice at all. This thread first mention I've seen on the internet of this turn away from sagas. Maybe should be in upgrade guide.

Comment: Ultimately I did find that configureStore and Sagas do play nice, but the documentation isn't terribly clear on how. This is a good code example of them cooperating https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/recipes#batching-actions Compared to redux-saga in the past I needed to wrap my watcher saga array in an "all()" redux-sagas/effects function